App fails when trying to retrieve ID auto increment Android
I am trying to get the last added or inserted record in the sqlite database/table based on the auto increment "id" Integer, but my app keeps crashing.
Here is my Kotlin code.
@SuppressLint("Range")
fun getLast(): Int {
val db = databaseHelper.readableDatabase

val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE MAX(id)",null)

if (cursor.count>0) {
cursor.movetofirst()
return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))  <---- FAILS and app crashes.
}
}

An arrow pointing to the offending like is the cause of my app failure.
However, in other functions I do exactly that for different columns and it works no problem at all like the following.
// iterate through the cursor and add the data to the list
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
val Sensor_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sensor_name"))  <----- This line works.
val Sensor_reading = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sensor_reading"))   <----- This line works.
list.add(Sensor(Sensor_name, Sensor_reading))
}

So, how do you search and retrieve auto increment ID column from SQLite database/table using SQL in Kotlin?

In your first code snippet, you are not doing anything to see if you got any rows back and then move the cursor to the first row. Since the cursor is not positioned on a row, you crash when you try to retrieve a column value. In your second code snippet, you are moving the cursor around its rows before you try retrieving any column values.

yes, i have, but i just dont show it here. still, no matter what app fails at that line. id is an integer,

@ThN - Please share the stack trace associated with the crash.
